# getURLParameter and RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am very new to jQuery and javascript. I am trying to understand the piece of code below. Can anyone explain to me what the parameter "name" is suppose to be? Is it the url? (i.e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Also can you also explain how `location.search.match.RegExp("[?|&]" + name + '=(.+?)(&|$)'))` works. It would be really great if someone can use this in an example with an input for "name" and display the output.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     function getURLParameter(name) {

         return decodeURIComponent(
         (location.search.match(RegExp("[?|&]" + name + '=(.+?)(&|$)')) || [, null])[1]);

     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`name` is called a function's *parameter*. When the function is called it uses this parameter to search the query string portion of the browser's URL for any parameter matching this `name` and returns its *value*. A query string is specified as (at the minimum): `?parameter1=value1` with any number of additional/optional parameters separated with a `&`, ie. `?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2`. If the `name` parameter is not found, the function returns `null`.

As for the Regular Expression, it is used to search the query string as mentioned above. it looks for either a "?" or "&" followed by `name` followed by "=" and one or more of any characters. The `[]` treats every character inside literally. The `|` is simply a standard or operator. It also throws this value of one or more characters into a *capture group* (by wrapping that part of the RegEx in parenthesis). The last bit ensures that it is either the end of the string after this value or that there is a "&" proceeding it (most likely followed by another query parameter and value). When the function returns `[1]` it is returning the second value in the match result array which is the above mentioned capture group, or simply the `name` parameter's value (*or* null if no match is found).

Comment: Love your explanation of RegExp! Question: Why do we use "[]" notation before name and "()" after? Is this just standard syntax?

Comment: That's actually an error by whoever wrote the expression. It should be : `location.search.match(RegExp("[?&]" + name + '=(.+?)(?=&|$)'))`. The last part is a lookahead which only matches the preceding part if the part inside these parethesis is found afterwards.

Comment: `[]` simply treats characters within literally. You can also specify ranges like "a-z" for all lowercase latin characters. If we didn't write `[?&]` we would have to escape the "?" with a "\" since it has a special meaning in regular expressions and include the or operator like so: `\?|&`.

Answer (score 0):

`name` looks like a query string key, i.e. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?name=foo`

Which would result in

```
console.log(getURLParameter('name')); //foo
```

What the function does is to search the url for a key prefixes with either `?` (first get parameter) or `&` (the rest of the parameters) and fetches the value.

Comment: Your example was perfect! I totally get it now. location.search gives "?name=foo" so that when you put in 'name' the function will return foo.